# Starting multiple tasks based on an event in iOS

Tags: ios, parallel-processing, bluetooth, queue

I am developing a bluetooth app using the EADemo example. Whenever there is data in the bluetooth inputStream, the following event is invoked:

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
{
    switch (eventCode) {
      case 1:
       //here I want to start two tasks
       break;

}
```

And I have a common queue to which I have to write and read parallely.
 The queue is actually a NSMutuableArray. In the write part, I use **addobject:**
 and in the read part, I use **objectAtIndex:0**.

Any one has any idea how to move about this?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using same array you will need to make it safe to access otherwise it may crash app

**APPROACH A:** (Using Grand Central Dispatch)

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0);//set priority as per requirement
```

*//Read*

```
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

                    while (//condition to stop)
                    {
                        //Perform read operation            
                    }
                });
```

*//Write*

```
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

                    while (//condition to stop)
                    {
                        //Perform write operation           
                    }
                });
```

//As operations are performed on same queue your array is safely accessed

**APPROACH B:** (Using threads)

Create two thread

1. Read Thread
2. Write tread

But access your array in synchronised manner.

Comment: in A: Both the dispatch_async gets started at the same time? Initially i thought of the same. But i was not sure of it.

Comment: As it is dispatch_async it will immediately go to next line without waiting for execution. So first block will get submitted and then second. How they get executed depends on how GCD provide them cpu cycles.

Comment: thanks for the idea. I ll try this later. For now I am able to access the queue for both operations. As i access different objects, there is no problem for now. :)